# How can I have "Table view" as the default result instead of "Submissions“

Tags: 7, webforms

When viewing the results page of a webform node, the submissions views is the default one.

We then have the possibility to display data using these secondary links:
Submissions, Analysis, Table, Download, and Clear.

I'm looking for a way to thange the order of these links.
I would like the table view to be the one displayed by default, instead of the submissions view.

The first part of the screenshot shows how the module works; the other half shows the order I would like for the tabs.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do this in a custom module. In your custom module, implement [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter.
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
   // Node webform results.
  $items['node/%webform_menu/webform-results'] = array(
    'title' => 'Results',
     // the page callback here is what will display the table.
    'page callback' => 'webform_results_table',
    'page arguments' => array(1, '50'),
    'access callback' => 'webform_results_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'file' => 'includes/webform.report.inc',
    // Change the weight to change the order
    'weight' => 0,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,

  );
}
```

Once you added that to your custom module. Make sure the module is enabled, and clear all caches.